# Identify unique value in a nested array structure

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON structure as below. So it is a dynamic structure e.g. for some rows, if there are 0 level 3 objects applicable (server logic), it would not have the containing level 2 itself. Similarly if there are 0 level 2 objects applicable, it would not have the entire level 1 object itself.

```
"level1":[
    {
        "id":"0",
        "index":"0",
        "label":"Level 1 Label a",
        "level2":[
            {
            "id":"0",
            "index":"0",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 1a",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId1","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label 00a"}
            ]
            },
            {
            "id":"1",
            "index":"1",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 1b",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId2","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label 00b"}
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id":"1",
        "index":"1",
        "label":"Level 1 Label b",
        "level2":[
            {
            "id":"0",
            "index":"0",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 2a",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId3","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label a"}
            ]
            },
            {
            "id":"1",
            "index":"1",
            "label":"Level 22 Label",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId3","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label b"}
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

Now my question is I need to find a given unique Id (e.g. UniqueId3) in this structure and return a boolean (true/false).
This unique id, if present, would be always at level 3
I know one way is I can iterate the array and check. But just wanted to understand if there is a better way.

Updated code to check;

```
resp.forEach((level1) => {
level1.groups.forEach((level2subGroup) => {
level2subGroup.level3.forEach((level3Item) => {
if (level3Item.id === IdToCompare) {alert('match found')}
})
})
})
```

Comment: I think there is no way but to iterate the array to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a text search:

```js
const ob={"level1":[
    {
        "id":"0",
        "index":"0",
        "label":"Level 1 Label a",
        "level2":[
            {
            "id":"0",
            "index":"0",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 1a",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId1","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label 00a"}
            ]
            },
            {
            "id":"1",
            "index":"1",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 1b",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId2","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label 00b"}
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id":"1",
        "index":"1",
        "label":"Level 1 Label b",
        "level2":[
            {
            "id":"0",
            "index":"0",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 2a",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId3","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label a"}
            ]
            },
            {
            "id":"1",
            "index":"1",
            "label":"Level 22 Label",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId3","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label b"}
            ]
        }]
    }
]}

const id="UniqueId3"

const found = JSON.stringify(ob).indexOf(id) > -1

console.log(found)
```

note: if you're getting this from a server, most probably you don't need to stringify an object, you'll just search on the JSON that you got from the server

Comment: What if one of the values in the JSON is the same as the id you search but it is not the value of id?

Comment: @ikhvjs I trust OP when he states "This unique id, if present, would be always at level 3" so 1) it's unique 2) it's at the desired level. If you could have a collision between, let's say, the id and label, then you need to perform a regex test against id\":<<id-to-search>>

Comment: @malarres - Thanks...yes, so the code given by you should work mostly. However, just thinking about a rare possibility that this id string might appear at some other place as well....If I have to do a search on this specific level (by iterating over the entire json), would that be a bit complex ?

Comment: Or....is it atleast possible that I find an exact word match against id...coz that should atleast eliminate the contains/partial word use cases

Comment: @malarres - I updated my original question with one of the approach I had in my mind (checking at specific level3)...Not sure if there is better way to do that...since trying to avoid forEach

Comment: @copenndthagen `.some()` would be better than `foreach` though technically this is still "iterate the array and check"

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to "I know one way is I can iterate the array and check. But just wanted to understand if there is a better way" but derived from the comments on my other answer, a reply to OP's "trying to avoid forEach"

For that, you can use `.some()` that stops when a solution is found (in the worst case -not found- it's still the same iteration)

```js
const ob={"level1":[
    {
        "id":"0",
        "index":"0",
        "label":"Level 1 Label a",
        "level2":[
            {
            "id":"0",
            "index":"0",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 1a",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId1","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label 00a"}
            ]
            },
            {
            "id":"1",
            "index":"1",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 1b",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId2","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label 00b"}
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id":"1",
        "index":"1",
        "label":"Level 1 Label b",
        "level2":[
            {
            "id":"0",
            "index":"0",
            "label":"Level 2 Label 2a",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId3","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label a"}
            ]
            },
            {
            "id":"1",
            "index":"1",
            "label":"Level 22 Label",
            "level3":[
                {"id":"UniqueId3","index":"0","label":"Level 3 Label b"}
            ]
        }]
    }
]}


const ob2 = {a:"b",c:[{d:"e"}]}


const findL3Id = (obj,id) => !!obj.level1?.some(l1 => l1.level2.some(l2 => l2.level3.some(l3 => l3.id == id)))

console.log(findL3Id(ob,"UniqueId3"))
console.log(findL3Id(ob2,"UniqueId3"))
console.log(findL3Id(ob,"blabla"))
console.log(findL3Id(ob,"1"))  // 1 is a level2 id
```